# How to create largest non-overlapping interval containing both, start/end dates?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to construct SQL code that return me the largest non-overlapping interval containing both, start and end dates.

[image]

[image]

In this case, I would like to return 2 intervals such as from Jan-Jun and Jun-Aug. How would I do this in SQL? I am assuming maybe some sort of self join?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help, please have a read of how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Stu I just added the table structure with sample data. Hope that makes it more clear. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given table: test (id int, s date, e date)

Find the rows which have no corresponding superset row.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM      test AS t1
  LEFT JOIN test AS t2
    ON t1.s >= t2.s AND t1.e <= t2.e
   AND (t1.e - t1.s) < (t2.e - t2.s)
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
;
```

The join itself returns all rows from test (t1), along with the corresponding superset rows (t2) found.  The rows which have no corresponding superset rows produce `t2.id` of `NULL`

This does not attempt to address the case where two rows have identical `start` and `end`.  This is doable, but not explicitly required by the question.